# Is this metal-ball launching device realistic?

Tags: applied-mechanics, dynamics, solid-mechanics

For a school project (college level in "engineering" studies), a classmate and I are trying to design a device that would propel a metal ball of about 0.8 kg to distances up to 12-14m. Its intended purpose is to "play" the game of pétanque https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9tanque. We would like to be able to give a ball the most accurate initial angle and speed that we possibly can. The simplest devices we could think of, namely a simple rail or a pendulum, would need to be too big for the required scales as simple calculations show.

After thinking about railguns and coilguns and coming to the conclusion that these would need capacitors and other components outside of our budget and expertise, we thought about a simpler mechanical system but are unsure whether the required torque and overall machinery are sound or not:

[image: Device]

The rotating rod is supposed to push the ball. Now, as a sufficiently powerful electric motor would also be out of question, we thought about connecting the axis of the rod to a flywheel once such flywheel reaches a precalculated speed, based on the angular momentum/energy required to throw the ball fast enough. The angular momenta and speed calculations seem to check out even with mediocre efficiency but as primarily math&CS students, mechanical engineering isn't our strongest suit so we would like advice.

Even if it worked, the idea still poses a challenge since it requires connecting the two axes at the right time (although the flywheel should be heavy enough that the timing isn't so critical).Although there probably are more serious solutions to this problem, we thought about using heavy duty Velcro-like tape to connect the two axes, assuming the axis supporting the flywheel could move linearly while in operation (with a force exerted by the user).
This is because of simplicity and budget constraints, but seems like the second most important uncertainty point.

The flywheel is yet another point where things could go wrong; if the idea works we'll use one made from scratch as depicted in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBjuLDIjgkQ.

What is your opinion ?
1)Does this seem physically sound ?
2)If so, would it be hard to engineer and build with a few preferably unexpensive tools ?
3)What kind of accuracy level can we expect (best case) from such a crude design ?

Other (reasonable)device ideas are appreciated.

Comment: So how much energy does a tennis ball machine need? easy enough to find out, and while you are there you can get the mass of a tennis ball. That should enable you to guesstimate the needs for your ball.

Comment: @SolarMike we estimated the required kinetic energy to propel a  *pétanque* ball a few meters far (not taking air resistance into account). It seems feasible enough but I'm asking whether the system is actually sound or not.+ how hard it would be to build it.

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a flywheel method without such critical timing? Your method also involves off-axis forces and large impact forces where the other methods do not. Have you seen how tennis ball or baseball launchers work? They just use two flywheels and a feed mechanism. No timing, no resetting, no off-axis forces, no impact, and easily self-loading. You don't even need a tube with cutouts in it which can be a surprisingly tricky thing to fabricate.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks, we'll consider this option.

Comment: Think about various ball games. Loosely speaking you have thrown, kicked, or hit with a stick. The balls in each case are variable, soft, and hard. The range is short, medium, long. The accuracy is high, low, low. Why are you replicating a hit with a stick mechanism rather than an arm?